# How to lock threads in real-time applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Absolute multi-threading newbie here.

I have a multimedia application that plays music. Specifically, it has an audio thread that reads some data - e.g. a waveform - and sends it to the sound card. This is a real-time operation, so it must be executed as quick as possible in a "non-blocking" way.

On the other side there is another thread that takes care of the user interface. Here the user can perform some operations on that data - e.g. modify the waveform by adding or removing chunks. This of course should be possible, but the audio thread must keep running undisturbed with that data always available.

My first idea was something like this (c++-ish pthread pseudo code):

Audio thread:

```cpp
vector<sample> samples; // this is shared between this thread and the UI thread
mutexLock();
for (Sample sample : samples)
    play(sample);
mutexUnlock();
```

And the UI thread:

```cpp
void onEditSample()
{
    while (mutexTryLock() == 0)
    {
        editSamples(samples);
        mutexUnlock();
        break;
    }
}
```

But I'm not really sure about the try-lock part. What is in your opinion the best way to deal with this?

Comment: You might want to study the classes and features of the standard [Thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). As is your question is too broad to give you concise advice, that would be helpful for future researchers hitting your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I love threads from the Standard Library. However I'm kind of stuck with pthreads for now. Anyway, the underlying theory should be the same, right?

Comment: I'd recommend you write wrapper classes for the underlying pthreads functions if you can't use the current c++11 standard library. You can easily come up with the same interfaces, and all the principles (especially using RAII and lock guards would be the same).

Comment: You probably want to send the wave to be played in small buffer loads to the sound system, only locking the wave to copy each buffer. Also use a **read lock** from the playing thread and a **write lock** on the wave form editing thread, but **only** after the completed edit is ready to be copied over the shared wave form.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no point using a Try Lock in the UI thread in a loop like.  Just an ordinary lock will be fine - the only thread it's going to block is the UI thread, not the playing thread.

Now,

> This is a real-time operation, so it must be executed as quick as
>   possible in a "non-blocking" way.

This is not quite correct.  It doesn't need to be executed as *quickly* as possible - it needs to be executed within certain timeliness limits.  (New samples must be provided before the sound device finshes playing the last set of samples - there is a deadline which must be met).

So, given that the mutex will be locking the audio thread out while the UI thread updates the sample, what we have is that the audio thread must not be blocked for too long, so the UI thread must only hold the mutex for a short time.

To minimize the amount of time the UI thread holds the mutex, you must minimize the amount of work it needs to do to update the samples.  One way to do this is to use *double-buffering* - you have two vectors of samples, with one that is actively being used by the audio thread indicated by a pointer.  When the UI thread wants to update the samples, it copies the new samples into the inactive vector (*without* holding the mutex), then takes the mutex, swaps the pointer value to the other vector, and unlocks the mutex.  The mutex is then only held for the length of time it takes to update a single pointer value, which is very short.

Comment: Great explanation, especially for the double-buffering trick (I wasn't aware of). You wrote "the only thread it's going to block is the UI thread, not the playing thread". How come? Is it because of the double-buffering optimization?

Comment: @Ignorant: No, I mean that if the try lock is called in the UI thread and returns an error without blocking (because the mutex is already held by another thread), then the only thread that *would* have blocked in that situation (with an ordinary mutex lock) is the UI thread.  A try lock only helps the *calling thread*, and is only useful if that thread has something else it could usefully be doing without the mutex anyway.